# Set a variable value in one function and use in other functions, when called directly from link in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've tried a lot but I am not getting my requirement.
I have a controller in which I declared a private var and assigning this in one of the function of the controller. Then I want to use it in another function when called from 
a link directly that function.

```
        class Xyz extends CI_Controller {
            private $var;
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->var = null;
            }

            public function getGenVal(){
                $this->var = $_REQUEST['value']; //Setting the global variable
            }

            //Calling bellow function directly from a link
            public function globalVarValue(){
                $val = $this->var;
                echo $val;  //Nothing displayed.
            }
        }
```

Comment: add `error_log()` statements in each of your methods, then look at the server's error log.  You will probably find your methods are not being called in the order you expect them to.

Comment: everytime construct gets called and it sets $this->var to null

Comment: if you want to directly hit the link then you can use session userdata to set and get values

Comment: @hrishi any example please...

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: @hrishi,Thank you Hrishi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  class Xyz extends CI_Controller {
        private $var;
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->var = null;
        }

        public function getGenVal(){
            $this->session->set_userdata('val',$_REQUEST['value']); //Setting the global variable
        }

        //Calling bellow function directly from a link
        public function globalVarValue(){
            if($this->session->userdata('val'))
            {
               echo  $this->session->userdata('val'); 
            }

        }
    }
```