# Access global variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a file in my code which is included in my all projects files as like we include header and footer. In that I am displaying some data. I wrote one model to fetch the data and I have written following code to access that data in my all controller.

```
   Model :
       public function get_signup_box_text() 
       { 
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('am_homepage_management');
            $this->db->where('section_name', 'left_note_signup_box');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->row_array(); 
        }


    Controller:
        $data['signup_box_text'] = $this->common_model->get_signup_box_text();
```

Ok, But I want to collect "signup_box_text" data in global variable and want to show that data in my included file.

Can anyone help me for this ?

Thank You.

Comment: you can use `define('Global_Variable', 'Any_Value');`

Comment: Nope, I dont want that. Can I declare it in controller file and then access to that view file  without adding same code in another controller?

Comment: use session userdata  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144768/set-a-variable-value-in-one-function-and-use-in-other-functions-when-called-dir?noredirect=1#comment77285871_45144768

Comment: any  other way ?

Comment: I think it is efficient way. once set in userdata you can access where you want

Comment: So to be clear you want to set a variable in one controller, but make it available in other unrelated views?

Comment: Create a MY_Controller extending the CI_Controller and define the property as public in it (inside the application/core directory). Then extend MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller in all your controllers. The property will be available in all controllers.

Comment: See, I have one subscribe.php file where I am showing some text which is coming from database. As mentioned above, I wrote a model for that. Ok, This file is going to be included in all the project view files. If suppose file1.php has its controller and file2.php has its other controller. If I want that text, currently, I am writing "$this->common_model->get_signup_box_text();" in both the controller, due to that, two times query is executing which is wrong. So, for that, I want to collect the result in global variable and wanted to user in all files just by accessing the name of the variable

Comment: you can use [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Comment: @Punam, If every time your result is not going to change you can also use [caching](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/caching.html)